# Photoshop CS6 Colors Look Terrible!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile

I just installed Photoshop CS6 for the first time (after coming from CS5). I tried taking a screenshot of a website I like to sample the blue color in the screenshot, but as soon as I paste it in Photoshop the colors become extremely dull. I've included the website behind the screenshot in photoshop so you can see how terribly different the blues look.

My settings are completely stock, RGB 8 bit. I'm not used to having to mess with color profiles just to get a screenshot to look okay in PS. Does anybody have some insight for me?

Greatly appreciated!

[image: The picture ...]

Comment: calibrated your monitor recently?

Comment: Dual monitors ;)

Comment: Okay.. calibrated them both? Same brand? Same pixel density? Dual monitors means nothing.. I run 3 and as long as they are calibrated, they all look the same.... I don't get your point.

Answer (score 2):

Check your color profile in Edit > Color Settings (ctrl+shift+k). Is your color profile set to SRGB? If it is, switch it to Adobe RGB, and while you're at it sync your color profiles across the suite with Bridge so that you don't have to worry about color shift between applications.

Edit: Also, Chrome and Firefox both have extensions you can use to sample color directly from your browser and automatically save the value to your clipboard for use in other applications. If you're on Chrome, I recommend ColorZilla; I don't remember what the Firefox equivalent is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer on the topic:
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/9241/3901

The situation is getting slightly more complex over time though, because Safari 6 now assumes images with no profile are sRGB.